# Android Studio 1.4 and Gradle Build 1.3.0 Compatibility Issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-6.0-marshmallow

As soon as I added the following lines of script inside my app/build.gradle file,

```
buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        }
    }
```

I'm seeing a bunch of random errors like the following,

```
/..../res/drawable-xxxxhdpi: Error: Invalid resource directory name** for this file
```

Seems like there's been issues with Android Studio and Gradle Build 1.3.0. Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Is `xxxxhdpi` even a valid qualifier??

Comment: Yes. That's clearly not the issue as I had no problem with those with older version of sdk. Thanks though!

Comment: Alright, good to know, thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959927/gradle-build-error-with-api-23

Comment: Seems like that's also by me lol